# Doubt on wordings on the duplicate flag

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Flag says,

> **it is a duplicate...**
>   This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

And this is not the case always. For example,

1. https://stackoverflow.com/q/28297993/17447
2. [adding textbox in dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28295888/17447)

The two questions are the same, but it doesn't *already has an answer.*
Am I flagging it correctly?

Comment: The second has answers. Just not an *accepted* answer. To the community at large this should matter little.

Comment: Besides - they're by the same user, and they're the same question. Of course they're duplicates.

Comment: J Steen: So, is it ok to repeat the same question if its not answered?

Comment: No. Definitely not.